# io_service run within thread

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-thread

Why in this simple class if i use directly **io.run()** the function will be invoked otherwise if demand the run to other thread the print will not be invoked?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace std;

class test
{
  public:
    test()
    {
      io.post(boost::bind(&test::print, this));
      //io.run();
      t = boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));
    }

    void print()
    {
      cout << "test..." << endl;
    }

  private:
    boost::thread t;
    boost::asio::io_service io;
};

int main()
{
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thread object is being destroyed before allowing the `io_service` to completely run.  The `thread` destructor [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.destructor) states:

> [...] the programmer must ensure that the destructor is never executed while the thread is still joinable.

If `BOOST_THREAD_PROVIDES_THREAD_DESTRUCTOR_CALLS_TERMINATE_IF_JOINABLE` is defined, the program would abort as the thread destructor would call `std::terminate()`.

---

If the `io_service` should run to completion, then consider joining the thread within `Test`'s destructor.  Here is a complete example that [demonstrates](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5013a39962e313c5) synchronizing on the thread's completion:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class test
{
public:
  test()
  {
    io.post(boost::bind(&test::print, this));
    t = boost::thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io));
  }

  ~test()
  {
    if (t.joinable())
      t.join();  
  }

  void print()
  {
    std::cout << "test..." << std::endl;
  }

private:
  boost::thread t;
  boost::asio::io_service io;
};

int main()
{
  test();
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
test...
```

Answer (score 1):

io_service::run() will complete all outstanding tasks and return when complete. If you don't call it, it will do nothing. If you do something like this:

```
boost::asio::io_service::work work(io);
```

Another thread will do this for you and run until you stop it one way or another.

Comment: **work** not call run. It's used to keep alive the io_service waiting other tasks. Run is called within bind.